# Comparing Equating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with Lagrangian Optimization

Tags: calculus

Let's say we're trying to find the maximum of the function $f(x, y) = x^2y$ subject to the constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. You can see this problem solved using Lagrangian Optimization in the following [Khan Academy Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aep6lwPqm6I&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&index=94).

However, it can also be solved by equating $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$, as follows:

Starting with the constraint:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1,$$
we can differentiate it implicitly, giving:
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = -\frac{x}{y}.$$

Then, we can express the differential of $f(x,y)$:
$$d(f(x,y)) = 2xy\,dx + x^2\,dy;$$
and since we are assuming we're staying on a contour line, we have $d(f(x,y)) = 0$, which leads to:
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = -\frac{{2xy}}{{x^2}} = -\frac{{2y}}{{x}}.$$

Equating the two expressions for $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$, we have:
$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{{2y}}{{x}},$$
which, after some algebra, gives the same solution as Lagrangian Optimization.

What are some pros and cons to equating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ vs using Lagrangian optimization? This question may lead to an interesting discussion on the efficiency, applicability, and insights that both methods offer in solving constrained optimization problems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry bot, I accidentally pressed the submit button before the question was done!

Comment: also you need to check whether $y\ne 0$ or $x\ne0$ before dividing

Comment: Yes, important point, I wrapped that up with "after some algebra"...

Comment: @daw As far as I can see, $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ doesn't give any real solutions, which seems reasonable since then there aren't any reals for which the two curves coincide.

Comment: In your approach you lose the critical points with $x=0$ or $y=0$, which is not a problem for the Lagrangian one.

Comment: $x^2=1-y^2, $ Hence it suffices to consider $y-y^3$ for $ -1\le y\le 1$ and apply one variable methods.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not related to what the OP wants to know, but still it's a good method so I would like to post it.**

By using AM-GM inequality,
$$\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot y^2}$$ or we can also say that $$x^2 y\le\sqrt{\frac{4}{27}}$$
Or $$\operatorname{max is} \frac{2\sqrt3}{9}$$